# Maven TestNG XSLT plugin issue - Plugin Not found error

Tags: xslt, selenium, maven-2, testng

I am trying to generate TestNG XSLT report using the Maven setup for selenium Tests.

http://code.google.com/p/testng-xslt/

I have configured the pom file with Maven plugin specified as above, but I am always getting plugin not found error. I am getting default TestNT report and not the XSLT report with chart.

Pom.xml used for the Test

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>uk.co.newsint.acs.admin.test</groupId>
<artifactId>ACS</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>testng-xslt-plugin</id>
        <url>http://www.cosminaru.ro/maven/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
           <configuration>
                 <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.testng.xslt</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng-xslt-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
                <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
                <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,PASS,SKIP,CONF</testDetailsFilter>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 1):

First why are you using such an old [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) version? Current version is 2.12.4...Furthermore you shouldn't define [repositories into your pom](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/) better use a repository manager instead.
Based on the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/testng-xslt/wiki/MavenPlugin) your definition of the repository is wrong. It should be:

```
<pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
       <id>testng-xslt-plugin</id>
       <url>http://uhftopic.com/maven/</url>
   </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

BTW: How have you called maven? mvn site to get the new reports ?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, khmarbaise's post is not an answer. I dont have enough reputation points that I can add comments but I wanted to put this thing in notice that using http://uhftopic.com/maven/ is not correct as it is appearing offline. Please take look at this post 
[Unable to generate XSLT in maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916367/unable-to-generate-xslt-in-maven-project/18960344?noredirect=1#comment28148403_18960344)